# Camera error 2 android 6.0

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-6.0-marshmallow

Please help to understand what means: E/Camera: Error 2.
My Camera-code does not work on android 6.0 only and the other works. This code is to scan a qr code. On the 6.0 preview is not included but you can include flash.
Runtime permissions is active. 
Sometimes: W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: getParameters failed (empty parameters) in onPreviewFrame.

SimpleCameraView:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import java.util.List;

public class SimpleCameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
 private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
 private Camera camera;
 private Camera.PreviewCallback previewCallback;
 private Display display;

 public SimpleCameraView(Context context, Camera.PreviewCallback previewCallback) {
 super(context);
 this.previewCallback = previewCallback;
 this.display = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
 this.surfaceHolder = this.getHolder();
 this.surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
 this.surfaceHolder.setType(3);
 this.setKeepScreenOn(true);
 this.configureCamera(this.getResources().getConfiguration());
 }

 public Camera getCamera() {
 try {
 this.camera = Camera.open();
 //this.camera.lock();
 Log.e("1111111","getCamera");
 } catch (Exception var2) {
 var2.printStackTrace();
 }

 return this.camera;
 }

 public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
 try {
 this.camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
 Log.e("1111111","surfaceCreated");
 } catch (Exception var3) {
 var3.printStackTrace();
 }

 }

 public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

 this.stopCamera();
 Log.e("1111111","surfaceDestroy");
 }

 public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
 startCamera();
 Log.e("1111111","surfaceChanged");
 }

 public boolean configureCamera(Configuration configuration) {
 try {
 this.getCamera();
 if (this.camera != null) {
 int e = this.getScreenWidth();
 int height = this.getScreenHeight();
 int displayOrientationDegrees = this.getDisplayOrientationDegrees(this.display);
 this.camera.setDisplayOrientation(displayOrientationDegrees);
 Camera.Size previewSize = this.camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
 float aspect = (float) previewSize.width / (float) previewSize.height;
 ViewGroup.LayoutParams cameraHolderParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(480,640);
 if (configuration.orientation == 1) {
 cameraHolderParams.height = height;
 cameraHolderParams.width = (int) ((float) height / aspect);
 } else {
 cameraHolderParams.width = e;
 cameraHolderParams.height = (int) ((float) e / aspect);
 }

 this.setLayoutParams(cameraHolderParams);
 Log.e("1111111","configureCamera");
 return true;
 }
 } catch (Exception var8) {
 var8.printStackTrace();
 }

 return false;
 }

 private int getScreenWidth() {
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 13) {
 return this.display.getWidth();
 } else {
 Point size = new Point();
 this.display.getSize(size);
 return size.x;
 }
 }

 private int getScreenHeight() {
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 13) {
 return this.display.getHeight();
 } else {
 Point size = new Point();
 this.display.getSize(size);
 return size.y;
 }
 }

 private int getDisplayOrientationDegrees(Display display) {
 int orientation = this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
 short displayOrientationDegrees;
 switch (display.getRotation()) {
 case 0:
 if (orientation == 1) {
 displayOrientationDegrees = 90;
 } else {
 displayOrientationDegrees = 0;
 }
 break;
 case 1:
 if (orientation == 2) {
 displayOrientationDegrees = 0;
 } else {
 displayOrientationDegrees = 270;
 }
 break;
 case 2:
 if (orientation == 1) {
 displayOrientationDegrees = 270;
 } else {
 displayOrientationDegrees = 180;
 }
 break;
 case 3:
 if (orientation == 2) {
 displayOrientationDegrees = 180;
 } else {
 displayOrientationDegrees = 90;
 }
 break;
 default:
 displayOrientationDegrees = 0;
 }

 return displayOrientationDegrees;
 }

 public void stopCamera() {
 try {
 this.camera.stopPreview();
 this.camera.setPreviewCallback((Camera.PreviewCallback) null);
 this.camera.release();
 this.camera = null;
 Log.e("1111111","stopCamera");
 } catch (Exception var2) {
 var2.printStackTrace();
 }

 }

 public void startCamera() {
 try {
 if (this.surfaceHolder.getSurface() == null) {
 Log.e("1111111","null surface");
 return;
 }
 this.camera.reconnect();
 this.camera.setPreviewDisplay(this.surfaceHolder);
 if (this.previewCallback != null) {
 this.camera.setPreviewCallback(this.previewCallback);
 }
 Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
 Camera.getCameraInfo(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK, info);
 int rotate = (info.orientation + 360) % 360;
 Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
 params.setJpegQuality(50);
 params.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
 List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
 Camera.Size size = sizes.get(0);
 /*for (int i=0;i<sizes.size();i++)
 if (sizes.get(i).width > 1000 && sizes.get(i).width<1500)
 if (sizes.get(i).height < 2000 && sizes.get(i).height> 1500)
 size = sizes.get(i);*/
 if (size.width > 480) {
 for (int i = 0; i < sizes.size(); i++)
 if (sizes.get(i).width < size.width && sizes.get(i).width > 480)
 size = sizes.get(i);
 } else
 for (int i = 0; i < sizes.size(); i++)
 if (sizes.get(i).width > size.width && sizes.get(i).width < 1000)
 size = sizes.get(i);
 params.setPictureSize(size.width, size.height);
 params.setRotation(rotate);
 camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
 camera.setParameters(params);
 this.camera.startPreview();
 Log.e("1111111","startCamera");
 } catch (Exception var2) {
 var2.printStackTrace();
 }

 }
}
```

SimpleCameraView:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.AutoFocusCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Iterator;

import net.sourceforge.zbar.Image;
import net.sourceforge.zbar.ImageScanner;
import net.sourceforge.zbar.Symbol;
import net.sourceforge.zbar.SymbolSet;

public class SimpleScannerFragment extends Fragment {
 private ImageScanner scanner;
 private SimpleCameraView cameraView;
 private PackageManager packageManager;
 private Vibrator vibrator;
 private Handler configurationHandler = new Handler();
 private Handler autoFocusHandler = new Handler();
 private Runnable reconfigureRunnable = new SimpleScannerFragment.CustomConfigureRunnable();
 private Runnable runAutoFocus = new SimpleScannerFragment.CustomAutoFocusRunnable();
 private PreviewCallback previewCallback = new SimpleScannerFragment.CustomPreviewCallback();
 private AutoFocusCallback autoFocusCallback = new SimpleScannerFragment.CustomAutoFocusCallback();
 private ScannerListener scannerListener;

 public SimpleScannerFragment() {
 }

 public void setScannerListener(ScannerListener scannerListener) {
 this.scannerListener = scannerListener;
 }

 public SimpleCameraView getCamera() {
 return cameraView;
 }

 public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
 this.vibrator = (Vibrator) this.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
 this.scanner = new ImageScanner();
 this.scanner.setConfig(0, 256, 3);
 this.scanner.setConfig(0, 257, 3);
 Log.e("1111111","create");
 }

 public void onPause() {
 super.onPause();

 try {
 this.cameraView.stopCamera();
 this.stopAutofocus();
 Log.e("1111111","onpause");
 } catch (Exception var2) {
 var2.printStackTrace();
 }

 }

 public void onResume() {
 super.onResume();

 try {
 this.configureCamera();
 Log.e("1111111","onresume");
 } catch (Exception var2) {
 var2.printStackTrace();
 }

 }

 public void stopAutofocus() {
 if (this.isHaveAutoFocus() && this.cameraView.getCamera() != null) {
 this.autoFocusHandler.removeCallbacks(this.runAutoFocus);
 this.cameraView.getCamera().cancelAutoFocus();
 Log.e("1111111","stopautofocus");
 }

 }

 private void startAutofocus() {
 if (this.isHaveAutoFocus()) {
 this.autoFocusHandler.postDelayed(this.runAutoFocus, 3000L);
 this.cameraView.getCamera().autoFocus(this.autoFocusCallback);
 Log.e("1111111","startautofocus");
 }

 }

 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
 super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
 this.configureCamera();
 Log.e("1111111","onconfigurationchanged");
 }

 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 this.cameraView = new SimpleCameraView(inflater.getContext(), this.previewCallback);
 Log.e("1111111","createview");
 return this.cameraView;
 }

 private boolean isHaveAutoFocus() {
 if (this.packageManager == null) {
 this.packageManager = this.getActivity().getPackageManager();
 }

 return this.packageManager.hasSystemFeature("android.hardware.camera.autofocus");
 }

 private void configureCamera() {
 this.configurationHandler.postDelayed(this.reconfigureRunnable, 500L);
 Log.e("1111111","confCamera");
 }

 static {
 System.loadLibrary("iconv");
 }

 private class CustomPreviewCallback implements PreviewCallback {
 private long lastSnapshotTime;

 private CustomPreviewCallback() {
 }

 public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera incomingCamera) {
 try {
 if (System.currentTimeMillis() > this.lastSnapshotTime) {
 this.lastSnapshotTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 3500L;
 Camera.Parameters e = incomingCamera.getParameters();
 Size previewSize = e.getPreviewSize();
 Image barcode = new Image(previewSize.width, previewSize.height, "Y800");
 barcode.setData(data);
 if (SimpleScannerFragment.this.scanner.scanImage(barcode) != 0) {
 SymbolSet scannerResults = SimpleScannerFragment.this.scanner.getResults();
 if (SimpleScannerFragment.this.vibrator != null) {
 SimpleScannerFragment.this.vibrator.vibrate(300L);
 }

 Iterator i$ = scannerResults.iterator();

 while (i$.hasNext()) {
 Symbol symbol = (Symbol) i$.next();
 if (SimpleScannerFragment.this.scannerListener == null) {
 Toast.makeText(SimpleScannerFragment.this.getActivity(), symbol.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 } else {
 SimpleScannerFragment.this.scannerListener.onDataReceive(symbol.getData(), symbol.getType());
 }
 }
 }
 }
 } catch (Exception var9) {
 var9.printStackTrace();
 }

 }
 }

 private class CustomConfigureRunnable implements Runnable {
 private CustomConfigureRunnable() {
 }

 public void run() {
 try {
 boolean e = SimpleScannerFragment.this.cameraView.configureCamera(SimpleScannerFragment.this.getResources().getConfiguration());
 if (!e) {
 SimpleScannerFragment.this.configurationHandler.postDelayed(this, 500L);
 SimpleScannerFragment.this.cameraView.stopCamera();
 } else {
 SimpleScannerFragment.this.configurationHandler.removeCallbacks(this);
 SimpleScannerFragment.this.cameraView.startCamera();
 SimpleScannerFragment.this.startAutofocus();
 }
 } catch (Exception var2) {
 var2.printStackTrace();
 }

 }
 }

 private class CustomAutoFocusRunnable implements Runnable {
 private CustomAutoFocusRunnable() {
 }

 public void run() {
 try {
 if (SimpleScannerFragment.this.cameraView != null && SimpleScannerFragment.this.cameraView.getCamera() != null && SimpleScannerFragment.this.isHaveAutoFocus()) {
 SimpleScannerFragment.this.cameraView.getCamera().autoFocus(SimpleScannerFragment.this.autoFocusCallback);
 }
 } catch (Exception var2) {
 var2.printStackTrace();
 }

 }
 }

 private class CustomAutoFocusCallback implements AutoFocusCallback {
 private CustomAutoFocusCallback() {
 }

 public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
 SimpleScannerFragment.this.autoFocusHandler.postDelayed(SimpleScannerFragment.this.runAutoFocus, 3000L);
 }
 }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.vibrate" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
 android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature
 android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
 android:required="true" />
```

View:

```
<fragment
 android:id="@+id/scannerFragment"
 class="com.app.reclamavdom.app.SimpleScannerFragment"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

StackTrace:

```
    06-15 12:10:18.485 13037-13037/com.app.reclamavdom.app E/1111111: create
06-15 12:10:18.485 13037-13037/com.app.reclamavdom.app E/1111111: confCamera
06-15 12:10:18.486 13037-13037/com.app.reclamavdom.app E/1111111: onresume
06-15 12:10:18.571 13037-13122/com.app.reclamavdom.app D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

                                                                         [ 06-15 12:10:18.586 13037:13037 D/         ]
                                                                         HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xacbb29a0, tid 13037


                                                                         [ 06-15 12:10:19.067 13037:13122 D/         ]
                                                                         HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaec26630, tid 13122
06-15 12:10:19.083 13037-13122/com.app.reclamavdom.app I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-15 12:10:19.843 13037-13037/com.app.reclamavdom.app E/1111111: surfaceCreated
06-15 12:10:19.958 13037-13037/com.app.reclamavdom.app E/1111111: startCamera
06-15 12:10:19.958 13037-13037/com.app.reclamavdom.app E/1111111: surfaceChanged
06-15 12:10:19.990 13037-13037/com.app.reclamavdom.app I/Choreographer: Skipped 78 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-15 12:10:26.913 13037-13043/com.app.reclamavdom.app W/art: Suspending all threads took: 84.122ms
06-15 12:10:27.227 13037-13037/com.app.reclamavdom.app W/art: Verification of android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.getOverflowIcon() took 138.051ms
06-15 12:10:27.657 13037-13037/com.app.reclamavdom.app E/1111111: getCamera
06-15 12:10:27.658 13037-13037/com.app.reclamavdom.app E/1111111: configureCamera
06-15 12:10:27.671 13037-13037/com.app.reclamavdom.app E/1111111: startCamera
06-15 12:10:27.677 13037-13037/com.app.reclamavdom.app E/1111111: getCamera
06-15 12:10:27.677 13037-13037/com.app.reclamavdom.app E/1111111: startautofocus
06-15 12:10:27.696 13037-13037/com.app.reclamavdom.app I/Choreographer: Skipped 460 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-15 12:10:27.904 13037-13037/com.app.reclamavdom.app W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: getParameters failed (empty parameters)
06-15 12:10:27.904 13037-13037/com.app.reclamavdom.app W/System.err:     at android.hardware.Camera.native_getParameters(Native Method)
06-15 12:10:27.904 13037-13037/com.app.reclamavdom.app W/System.err:     at android.hardware.Camera.getParameters(Camera.java:1890)
06-15 12:10:27.904 13037-13037/com.app.reclamavdom.app W/System.err:     at com.app.reclamavdom.app.SimpleScannerFragment$CustomPreviewCallback.onPreviewFrame(SimpleScannerFragment.java:144)
06-15 12:10:27.904 13037-13037/com.app.reclamavdom.app W/System.err:     at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:1110)
06-15 12:10:27.904 13037-13037/com.app.reclamavdom.app W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-15 12:10:27.904 13037-13037/com.app.reclamavdom.app W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
06-15 12:10:27.904 13037-13037/com.app.reclamavdom.app W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
06-15 12:10:27.904 13037-13037/com.app.reclamavdom.app W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-15 12:10:27.904 13037-13037/com.app.reclamavdom.app W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
06-15 12:10:27.904 13037-13037/com.app.reclamavdom.app W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
06-15 12:10:27.905 13037-13037/com.app.reclamavdom.app E/Camera: Error 2
06-15 12:10:27.905 13037-13037/com.app.reclamavdom.app E/Camera: Error 2
06-15 12:10:30.708 13037-13037/com.app.reclamavdom.app E/1111111: getCamera
06-15 12:10:30.717 13037-13037/com.app.reclamavdom.app E/1111111: getCamera
06-15 12:10:30.717 13037-13037/com.app.reclamavdom.app E/Camera: Error 2
06-15 12:10:30.717 13037-13037/com.app.reclamavdom.app E/Camera: Error 2
```

Comment: what is your targetSDK? And please give stackTrace

Comment: give stack trace with error

Comment: Have you any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, i have no idea why it happens. But i worked with library for scan qr code. Try to use [it](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) , if you want

Comment: Unfortunatel, this library made for level SDK 22 max.

Comment: Maybe it will help you: "E/Camera: Error 2" in Camera.java means:`/**
     * Camera was disconnected due to use by higher priority user.
     * @see Camera.ErrorCallback
     */
    public static final int CAMERA_ERROR_EVICTED = 2;` But i dont know what is it

Comment: It seems like other app using camera and that app didn't close it.

Comment: This library has a special view for scanning qr code. You can use it with runtime permissions something like. `if (cameraPermissionGranted()) { scanner.setVisibility(View.Visible); }`

Comment: But emulator does not have apps which used camera... And i run my app after boot device. And it happens on 6.0 only.

Comment: I tryed zxing library. Thanks you a lot. May you give me advice? I want to call method "handleResult" to define qrcode manually, but it does not work because camera  object is null but preview creates.  Here my code:  handleResult(new Result((String)"123",null,null,null););

Comment: Try to read qr code from some qr code generator. Try [this](http://goqr.me/). You need to implement `ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler` in your `Activity/Fragment` and write `handleResult(Result result)`. And after this you can test with real qr code.  Try to read [this](https://www.numetriclabz.com/android-qr-code-scanner-using-zxingscanner-library-tutorial/) manual. I hope it will help you.

Comment: You did not undestood me. I scaned real qr code, all rigth. But i need to define qr code manually (if scan qr code impossible).

Comment: I already have some strings for qr codes and want to put it in handleResult method like this handleResult(new Result((String)"123",null,null,null);); It works but not correct, i cant activate flash for exaple.

Comment: did u find any solution to avoid camera error 2 ?

Comment: unfortunately no, i'm used ZXing instead this.

Comment: it seems that you use startCamera() twice in your code.i had the same error,and that is because i started to camera twice

Answer (score 2):

Try closing the camera properly when your app closes. Leaving sessions open might result in a `Could not open camera: Too many users (-87)` error, which does not appear under your app tag, therefore commonly missed in the logs.

If that's the case, restarting the device should get you up and running

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea to call `getParameters()` for camera object received in `onPreviewFrame()` callback. This object may be null, or not in an appropriate state. And even if this function succeeds, it's very very slow. So simply keep the preview size you configured as private members of your class, and use them instead of `getPreviewSize()` on every preview frame.

I would also recommend to create `Image barcode` once, outside the preview loop, and inside the callback only setData(). You will be surprised how slow such recurring allocations can be.

Answer (score 0):

I think you call your camera twice. In my case i open the camera in "onCreate" and "onResume" methods.

Answer (score 0):

Nitay answered correctly. I got this error when I tried to open camera (already opened) without closing the camera.

Already opened camera holding this!

```
cam.startPreview()
```

Before going to access another camera or an already opened camera you should close this one!

```
cam.stopPreview()
cam.release()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change the emulator configurations. Emulator Front and Back camera should be emulated instead of None/webcame0. These configurations will help you to resolve the issue.

Emulator

```
      Front camera: emulated
```

and

```
      Back camera: emulated
```